# Controlling/regulating water flow in a vertical pipe

Tags: water-pressure

[image]

In the image above, the 2nd pipe is used to dispense water. Only so much of consumed water flows down in the pipe. Hence there must be some mechanism used to hold the water in the pipe and allow water flow in a regulated manner. What could that mechanism be?

Comment: Play with this: take a 2-liter bottle fill it with water, turn it upside-down and place the open end of the bottle into an empty glass. Note the glass fills to the bottom of the bottle end. Note the similarity to the picture above. Try withdrawing water from the glass, until the water level falls below the bottle end. What happens? Can you explain this?

Comment: You may also have a look at [this video by **Practical Engineering** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=933XNdClFrc), as it illustrates some fascinating aspects of hydrostatics including this one (although I too recommend testing the experiment described by @JimClark first and making up some thoughts). I suggest watching the entire video, with your question in particular being brought up at 6:17.

Comment: [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/9OWfTFCMaUc) shows the technique to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same principle as used to make the mercury based barometers.

Check out Torricelli barometer,
Like this:

```
In 1644, Evangelista Torricelli described the first mercury barometer in a remarkable letter that contained the phrase, “We live submerged at the bottom of an ocean of the element air, which by unquestioned experiments is known to have weight.”
```

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3768090/